# Calculating a cokernel on wedge product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, multilinear-algebra

i have a question... maybe it is easy and im only doing some mistake.

Given a surjective homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^m$,
then its kernel $K_f$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{n-m}$.

1. How can i describe the kernel $K_{\wedge^k f}$ of $\wedge^k f \colon \wedge^k \mathbb{Z}^n 
   \rightarrow \wedge^k \mathbb{Z}^m$ in terms of $K_f$?
2. Now, consider an injective morphism $g\colon \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^p$,
   is the group $\wedge^k \mathbb{Z}^p / \wedge^k g (K_{\wedge^k f})$ isomorphic
   to some wedge product?

Thanks.

Comment: 2. should probably have some qualifications to it: what if we take Z -> Z degree 2 so that the quotient is Z/2?  also for vector spaces the first wedge product of V is just V...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Note that $f$ is not only a group homomorphism, but a $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism. Naturally, the map $\wedge^k f: \wedge^k \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \wedge^k\mathbb{Z}^m$ is defined as $a_1 \wedge \dots \wedge a_k \mapsto f(a_1) \wedge \dots \wedge f(a_k)$. Note that $f(a_1) \wedge \dots \wedge f(a_k) = 0$ if and only if the $f(a_1),\dots,f(a_k)$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly dependent, i.e. there exist $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, not all zero, such that
$$\sum_{i=}^k n_if(a_i) = f\left(\sum_{i=1}^k n_i a_i \right) = 0,$$
in other words, $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i a_i \in K_f$. If we assume that the $a_1,\dots,a_k$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent, their span $A$ in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^k$, and 
$$\wedge^k f(a_1 \wedge \dots \wedge a_k) = 0$$
if and only if $A \cap K_f$ is non-trivial.

I do not see how I could answer 2) without more specific information.

Comment: "Note that $f$ is not only a group homomorphism, but a $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism" what's the difference? Any group homomorphism (between abelian groups) is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: There's no difference. I could have done without this remark, but since I was explicitly using the $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure I thought it best to mention it.